# Where do I keep ORM in a distributed app?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am designing a scalable web app. I have APIs (Django Rest Framework) in one container instance, Web App (Django) in another, Database (Postgreql) in another and finally CDN in another (Azurite). I wanted to decouple API since mobile apps will use the same - eventually.

**Question:**

- Where do I keep ORM in this scenario?
- If I keep it part of Web apps, then how do the APIs recognize and use
  the objects?
- Or, if I keep them part of the API services, how do the front end
  (web apps) understand the objects?

Comment: How are you separating DRF and Django containers???

Comment: @AmirAfianian: I have created another project for DRF. Then I use tokens from Web app to the DRF

Comment: So, you basically have containerized two `Django` projects? I would consider both as one.

Comment: So, instead of keeping API standalone, I can keep it with the web app and then scale the container running web services instead. In this case I can continue using ORM in both API and webapp. Is that you are suggesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you keep your DRF code with the rest of Django and containerize them together.

As for the ORM, what matters is the container for `Postgres`. You cannot tear apart, say, `models` into a separate container.

To summarize, you can have the following containers:

1. One for DRF and Django
2. One for your Database layer (`Postgres`) for instance.
3. And one for your `CDN`.

Needless to say, you could containerize your webserver separately as well.